# phpunit 9 does not print error stack trace

Tags: phpunit

I recently updated my unit test environment from phpunit v8.5.13 to v9.5.1. Same config file, same php version, all the same except the php unit phar file in command line.

All works fine but when there araises a not expected exception then the stack trace is no longer printed (as it was until v8):

```
PHPUnit 9.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E

Time: 00:00.973, Memory: 42.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) moduleTmEmployeeTest::testAdd with data set "default" (array(), array())
mobEx: this is my exception

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

phpunit 8

```
PHPUnit 8.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E

Time: 1.36 seconds, Memory: 36.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) moduleTmEmployeeTest::testAdd with data set "default" (array(), array())
mobEx: this is my exception

[path]\unittests\phpunit\tm\moduleTmEmployeeTest.php:54

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I checked out docs and migration guide but got no clue which new flag to set or what else I could do. Does anyone know?

Comment: [Are you using PHPUnit from PHAR?](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4573)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As referenced by @sebastian in his comment, it's a bug fixed in current release v9.5.2.